# sympy factor simple relationship

Tags: python, sympy

I have a simple factorization problem in sympy that I cannot sort out.  I've had great success with sympy working with quite complex integrals, but I'm flummoxed by something simple.

How do I get

```
phi**2 - 2*phi*phi_0 + phi_0**2 - 8
```

to factor to

```
(phi - phi_0)**2 - 8
```

?

I've already tried the factor function

```
factor(phi**2 - 2*phi*phi_0 + phi_0**2 - 8,phi-phi_0)
```

which yields the same old solution.

Comment: You have a typo in your expected answer, should be `(phi - phi_0)**2 - 8`. (This isn't causing your problem but it might confuse someone.)

Comment: Thanks.  Typo corrected.

Comment: I think factor() simply cannot determine if it should use only a part of the expression. Consider factor(x**2 + 2*x + 2): how would it determine that +1 must be separated from the expression to allow factorization?

Comment: Yes I understand this is not a trivial problem to solve, but it seems like a tractable problem to solve

Comment: Such partial factorizations are not unique either.

Comment: What I don't understand is how sympy cannot do this factorization, as I am explicitly telling it I want to factor in terms of ``phi - phi_0``, which has only one solution for this case.  Or am I understanding wrong ?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure why allowing an expression like `phi - phi_0` as the second argument to `factor` is even allowed, since it isn't smart enough currently to recognize the algebraic relationship between it and the polynomial. In fact, that's exactly what would need to be implemented to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in the comment, such "partial factorizations" are not unique (for instance, `x**2 + 5*x + 7` equals `(x + 2)*(x + 3) + 1` and `(x + 1)*(x + 4) + 3`, and once you understand what's going on it's not hard to come up with examples of your own).

There are ways to do such things manually, but it's hard to know what to tell you because I don't know what generality you are looking for. For instance, probably the easiest way to do this particular example is

```
>>> print(A.subs(phi, x + phi_0).factor().subs(x, phi - phi_0))
(phi - phi_0)**2 - 8
```

That is, let `x = phi - phi_0` (SymPy isn't smart enough to replace `phi - phi_0` with `x`, but it is smart enough to replace `phi` with `x - phi_0`, which is the same thing). This doesn't generalize as nicely if you want to factor in terms of a larger polynomial, or if you don't know what you are aiming for. But given the names of your variables, I'm guessing `phi - phi_0` is all you care about.

Beyond this, I should point out that you can more or less do any kind of simplification you want by digging in and writing your own algorithms that dig into the expressions. Take a look at http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html to get you started. Also take a look at all the methods of `Expr`. There are quite a few useful helper functions if you end up writing such a thing, such as the various `as_*` methods.

Comment: I should also note that if you're only dealing with one variable the `decompose` function can be useful. Unfortunately, it doesn't support multivariate expressions yet.