# Simplify expression

Tags: math, expression, sympy

I have an expressions like:

```
a*b*c + d*e + f - g*h*h + i*a
```

In other words: terms can be either added or subtracted, and each term is a product of some of the symbols.

Is there a way to come up with a minimal/simpler expression, basically the reverse of expand? I tried `simplify` and `factor` but I cannot get them to work. For example:

```
a**4 - 4*a**3*b + 6*a**2*b**2 - 4*a*b**3 - a + b**4
```

should turn into:

```
(a - b)**4 - a
```

but it stays unchanged when using the said commands.

PS: If this is something what SymPy simply cannot do, could you please suggest an alternative which does this?

Comment: W|A doesn't reduce that formula the same way. What if you used an equation you know will simplify - [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%3A+a**4+-+4*a**3*b+%2B+6*a**2*b**2+-+4*a*b**3+-+a+%2B+b**4+)

Comment: @corn3lius - not sure I understand: `factor(a**4 - 4*a**3*b + 6*a**2*b**2 - 4*a*b**3 + b**4)` does work, yes. But the majority of expressions are almost never so simple...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997087/sympy-factor-simple-relationship/21067479#21067479 (which might be considered a duplicate of this question). Such "partial factorizations" are not well-defined, although there are tricks to get them if you know what the answer should look like.

Comment: @asmeurer Interesting! Although I'm not yet sure I understood how it works. Say I want to factor out `a*b - c*d`, what then?

Comment: @asmeurer I see that you are the developer of SymPy! I recently asked in the mailing list why can't SymPy do simplifications such as the one above automatically? Is there a fundamental problem? You mentioned uniqueness - isn't it possible to come up with arbitrary factorization as long as it has minimal number of operators, for example?

Comment: I am not *the* developer of SymPy. There are quite a few people who work on the project.

Comment: There may be a unique expression in terms of minimal operators, but I'm not sure if there is an algorithm to find it (and at any rate, it isn't implemented).

Comment: @asmeurer yes, sorry - not "the", but "a". Also, if you would care to expand your answer below about the .subs() trick, I will accept it, as it is perhaps the closest thing so far to what I try to achieve. The thing is it is not entirely clear to me how should I construct the substitution for arbitrary factors (e.g. the `a*b - c*d` from above)... Thanks in any case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [sympy factor simple relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20997087/sympy-factor-simple-relationship/21067479#21067479). SymPy's `factor` only knows how to factor the entire expression, but if you know the term you want to rewrite things in terms of, you can use a trick with subs, like:

```
>>> expr = a**4 - 4*a**3*b + 6*a**2*b**2 - 4*a*b**3 - a + b**4
>>> expr.subs(a, x + b).expand()
-b + x**4 - x
>>> expr.subs(a, x + b).expand().subs(x, a - b)
-a + (a - b)**4
```

Basically, let `x = a - b`, so that `a = x + b`. Then replace `a` with `x + b`, expand things out, and replace it back.

For your more complicated example, SymPy is actually smart enough to replace `a*b` in an expression correctly:

```
>>> expr = (a*b - c*d)**2 - a
>>> expr = expr.expand()
>>> expr
a**2*b**2 - 2*a*b*c*d - a + c**2*d**2
>>> expr.subs(a*b, x + c*d)
-a + c**2*d**2 - 2*c*d*(c*d + x) + (c*d + x)**2
>>> expr.subs(a*b, x + c*d).expand()
-a + x**2
>>> expr.subs(a*b, x + c*d).expand().subs(x, a*b - c*d)
-a + (a*b - c*d)**2
```

Another possible approach to this problem would be to try using factor on subsets of the terms in an expression (`itertools.combinations` could be useful here). For instance, to try factoring all combinations of all terms but one from your original expression:

```
>>> args = Add.make_args(expr)
>>> for comb in combinations(args, len(args) - 1):
...    print(factor(Add(*comb)) + Add(*(set(args) - set(comb))))
...
a**4 - 4*a**3*b + 6*a**2*b**2 - 4*a*b**3 - a + b**4
a**4 - 4*a**3*b + 6*a**2*b**2 - 4*a*b**3 - a + b**4
a**4 - 4*a**3*b + 6*a**2*b**2 - 4*a*b**3 - a + b**4
a**4 - 4*a**3*b + 6*a**2*b**2 - 4*a*b**3 - a + b**4
-a + (a - b)**4
a*(a**3 - 4*a**2*b + 6*a*b**2 - 4*b**3 - 1) + b**4
```

You could check `not isinstance(factored_expr, Add)` to filter out the ones that aren't factored.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the function in advance, then you can use more powerful software packages such as Maple to reduce the expression before putting it into your computer code. There is a optimization package in Maple, which reduces the expression into sub-expressions such that it takes advantage of repeated operations in the expression. Also you can factorize very complicated expressions in a much reliable way.

In addition such software also can create programming code as output, which you can directly paste in your program. If you do not have access to Maple or Mathematica software, you can also use a free (but powerful) software called maxima. http://maxima.sourceforge.net/

Comment: "If you know the function in advance" - which function? In the above example, I don't know `(a - b)**4 - a` of course, that's what I try to compute. But maybe I misunderstood what you meant...

Comment: I meant the expression `a**4 - 4*a**3*b + 6*a**2*b**2 - 4*a*b**3 - a + b**4`. You can use Maple to factorize it, and enter the output manually in to your code or use Maple to generate the code for you.

Comment: I just tried Maxima and it cannot simplify it and neither can W|A (IIRC runs on Mathematica). Unfortunately I don't have access to Maple.

Comment: @EcirHana I just tried your expression in Maple, it does not work in Maple either. However, if you remove `-a` it works. I think that even Maple will not be able to help you in a general case!

Comment: Thanks for trying it in Maple, that's very helpful information. Without `-a` it works in other tools, too.